# Call centre email handling

Tags: email, outlook, hosted-exchange

In my organisation we have 10 call centre staff that all use the same email address (on a hosted Exchange service) to respond to enquiries and actively send templated emails out.

It's getting pretty difficult to manage not to mention having 10 Outlooks accessing the one email account sometimes causes issues. For example, a simple email password change will result in the account being locked out due to multiple attempts with the old password. So we have to make sure all Outlooks are closed and so on... Not to mention each Outlook machine syncing 25gb of emails...

I was wondering what other organisations/people were doing to tackle this problem.

Comment: Distribution Group?

Comment: How about a ticketing system that monitors a specific email address? That helps with keeping things organized and tracked.

Comment: Yeah, a proper ticket system or CRM will be better at scale than a shared mailbox.

Comment: I'm looking at CRM systems at the moment. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Shared Mailboxes or (shudder) Public Folders that are mail enabled.  Any generic SMTP account such as Sales, Support, etc. are typically better off being setup this way so that multiple users can access them, respond, etc.